# Swift dynamic cast failed - Error when trying to run unit tests

Tags: objective-c, swift

Xcode Version 6.1.1 (6A2008a)

Error: libswiftCore.dylib`swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional 
and Swift dynamic cast failed

I am trying to test and I am coming across this error that I am unsure about how to fix. Can someone please shed some light on this?

Error happens:

The error happens with this cast:

```
var delegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
```

After reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26946677/uiapplication-sharedapplication-delegate-as-appdelegate-causes-exc-bad-acces): I deleted the AppDelegate.swift from the test target  but then I get an error when building as the compiler complains about not knowing about "AppDelegate" in the cast. I am confused?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so after a lot of messing about here is what solved the issue:

1. I removed all the test target membership from the files in the main (non-test) part of my application, including the AppDelegate.

[image]

2. I changed all the classes (in the main part of the application) that I needed to access (from the Test part of the application) to be public and also set these class's required methods to be public as well).
3. I imported the main project into each appropriate test classes with an `#import AppName` statement

Hope that saves some other people some time.. :)

Comment: this helps me a lot. The only bad thing is that you have to change everything to public :(

Comment: Step 3 is what i was missing after adding the swift files in my main projects to the test target. Thanks!!